# Is this usage of "last" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Let's say I have just written an argument for something in a text, and I then add: "Last argument implies that..."

Is that correct? Or should I add "That/the last argument implies that" or "The previous argument implies that..."

What is more correct, and more importantly, more formal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say 'The previous' is the most correct and formal.

Comment: _Last_ means 'final in a series' as well as 'most recent', so there is a possible implication that what you've just written is the last (and therefore final) argument you can make. _Previous_ has no such implication. Either one will need _the_, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Last* and *next* are sometimes used as determiners in deictic time expressions (cf. *this*):

> **Last week** I went to the store.
>   **This week** I went to the store.
>   **Next week** I'll go to the store.
>   I ate pizza **last time**.
>   I'll eat pizza **this time**.
>   I'll eat pizza **next time**.

But your noun phrase *last argument* is not a deictic time expression, so in that phrase *last* cannot be a determiner.  It must instead be an attributive adjective, modifying the following head noun.  That means your noun phrase *last argument* is incomplete—it needs a determiner, and the appropriate one to add is *the*:

> **The last argument** implies that …

*Previous* is never a determiner.  Like *last*, it would be attributive in your example, and again that would leave the determiner slot empty.  Let's add *the*:

> **The previous argument** implies that …

Either of these would work.  I think *last* is neutral with respect to formality, while *previous* is markedly formal.  Please see the comments for additional discussion.